# pycrypto and Google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, libraries, pycrypto

How do you use pycrypto with GAP?

It says [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries) that it does not support the latest version. Does that mean that I have to use the version pointed by them ?

I tried this but, when I execute `setup.py` I get the error `src/MD2.c:15:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`

Comment: probably you should use the correct tag google-app-engine instead of google-apps-script to get an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App Engine 1.7.2, released just a few hours ago, now supports PyCrypto 2.6, the most recent version. The linked doc is likely outdated and will be updated soon. You can use it by [instructing app engine to include it](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/migrate27#Configuring_Libraries).

Comment: I added the the pycrypto version 2.6 . When I run it local it works, when I deploy It gives me a server error when accessing the site.

Comment: @mjibsonIt was nothing relevant, just a server 500 error. No other info. Anyway, I managed to solve the problem. I was still including another library `passlib` in a file, at that was giving the error.

Answer (score 3):

To make GAE use pycrypto, you have to add the following to your app.yaml file:

```
libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: "2.6"
```

Like a charm, [code like](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Cipher.AES-module.html)

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get( self ) :
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    key = b'Sixteen byte key'
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    msg = iv + cipher.encrypt(b'Attack at dawn')
    self.response.write( msg )
```

Should work like a charm (actually triggers a download!)

[This information about what versions of what libraries are available are included here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27)

Answer (score 0):

GAP will not let you use the full version of pycrypto as it has lot of C so you can't deploy it and they will have to cut it down to what they can allow. You have to use `from google.appengine.dist import use_library` and then `use_library('lib', 'version.')`. Hopefully it is somewhat helpful.