# pycrypto random not supported on GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pycrypto

I have deployed a App engine application that uses pycrypto. I installed pycrypto locally but when i deploy on the App Engine it says:

```
TargetAppError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~shared-playground/55de226e3bc6746b0c2a029d52be624810ea0d14.376065013735366090/mimic/__mimic/target_env.py", line 968, in RunScript
    loader.load_module('__main__')
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~shared-playground/55de226e3bc6746b0c2a029d52be624810ea0d14.376065013735366090/mimic/__mimic/target_env.py", line 316, in load_module
    return self.env.LoadModule(self, fullname)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~shared-playground/55de226e3bc6746b0c2a029d52be624810ea0d14.376065013735366090/mimic/__mimic/target_env.py", line 725, in LoadModule
    exec(code, module.__dict__)  # pylint: disable-msg=W0122
  File "helloworld.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pycrypto import Random
ImportError: No module named pycrypto
```

I have the following app.yaml:

```
application: my-app-id
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: pycrypto
  version: "2.6"
```

My code is as follows:

```
import webapp2
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random

from google.appengine.api import users

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()

        if user:
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
            iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
            key = b'Sixteen byte key'
            cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
            msg = iv + cipher.encrypt(b'Attack at dawn')
            self.response.out.write('Hello, '+ msg + ': ' + user.nickname())


        else:
            self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage)
], debug=True)
```

The cause of the error seems fairly simple. There is no module named pycrypto. However the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504489/pycrypto-and-google-app-engine) suggest there is. What is the cause of this error then? Please advise thanks.

Comment: The traceback shows the line `from pycrypto import Random`, your code shows `from Crypto import Random`... ?

Answer (score 0):

App Engine provides third party libraries in their sandbox. Find the link[1] below for the 3rd party libraries supported by App Engine. Also you can try to change the version to **"latest"** instead of 2.6
in app.yaml

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27